# Filter by file size in Django (FileField)

Tags: django, django-orm, filefield

I have an a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name='File', upload_to="files/")
```

I can get file size in bytes:

```
size = my_model_instance.file.size
```

How to filter by file size in Django? Something like that:

```
MyModel.object.filter(file.size__lt=128)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. `model_instance.file.size` actually opens the associated file and fetches the size from disk. The only thing saved in the database is the path to the file.

If you want to be able to filter by file size, you'd have to save the size in the database as an extra field of your model. You could populate that field automatically when saving the model.

Comment: Thank you! I'll save file size as another field in model.